# Remove object value in array if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as follows

```js
const array = [ 
{id:1,parentIds:[]}
{id:2,parentIds:[1,3]}
{id:3,parentIds:[1,2,4]}
]
```

How can I make it possible to remove an object's parentIds value if it doesn't exist in the array? to look something like this

```js
const array = [ 
{id:1,parentIds:[]}
{id:2,parentIds:[1,3]}
{id:3,parentIds:[1,2]}
]
```

Comment: Why second `parentIds` is `[1]` not a `[1, 3]`? Both of 1 and 3 presents in array

Comment: What have you tried so far? With a loop you can get pretty far already!

Comment: Ah yeah that's right, 2nd one should [1,3]. Missed that

Comment: I am not sure how to approach this. I was thinking something using filtering and reduce rather than for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    parentIds: []
}, {
    id: 2,
    parentIds: [1, 3]
}, {
    id: 3,
    parentIds: [1, 2, 4]
}];

const idsArr = new Set(array.map(el => el.id));

array.forEach(el => {
    el.parentIds = el.parentIds.filter(el => idsArr.has(el));
})
    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Since the above approach already introduces the additional task of creating an `idsArr`, why not already creating a map like object in order to execute a fast lookup within the nested filter process instead of another iterating process like `includes`?

Comment: @PeterSeliger You are damn right! I think `Set` is more useful here. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

It's better to avoid mutating the original array `parentIds`, use immutation to create new array:

```
const array = [ 
{id:1,parentIds:[]},
{id:2,parentIds:[1,3]},
{id:3,parentIds:[1,2,4]}
]

const ids = array.map(({id}) => id)

const newArray = array.map(({parentIds,...arrayItemRest}) => {
  const newparentIds = parentIds.filter(id => ids.includes(id))
  
  return {
    ...arrayItemRest,
    parentIds: newparentIds
  }
})
```

Comment: Since the above approach already introduces the additional task of creating an `ids` array, why not already creating a map like object in order to execute a fast lookup within the nested filter process instead of another iterating process like `includes`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [ 
{id:1,parentIds:[]},
{id:2,parentIds:[1,3]},
{id:3,parentIds:[1,2,4]}
]

// Let's create an array only containing the ids
var ids = array.map(o => o.id)

// Loop array
array.forEach((object) => {
  // Loop all parent ids
  object.parentIds.forEach((id, index) => {
    // Check if we find the id in our list
    if (ids.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      // Delete item from array if not found
      object.parentIds.splice(index, 1)
    }
  })
})

// The result
console.log(array)
```

Comment: A filter and a foreach or two foreach is basically the same. I agree on the indexOf though and would also advise to use filter for this reason :)

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) your parent Ids and then filter using the `includes` method ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes))

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    parentIds: []
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    parentIds: [1, 3]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    parentIds: [1, 2, 4]
  }
]

const parents = array.map(x => x.id)

array.forEach(item => {
  item.parentIds = item.parentIds.filter(x => parents.includes(x))
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: We have 3 seconds differrence :)

Comment: Haha same solution sorry ^^

Comment: Everything is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of keys/ids using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and then `map` over the array of objects to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the parentIds that are missing, returning [a new array of updated objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const data=[{id:1,parentIds:[]},{id:2,parentIds:[1,3]},{id:3,parentIds:[1,2,4]}];

function removeIds(data) {
  
  // Get the ids from all the array objects
  const keys = data.map(obj => obj.id);
  
  // `map` over the array and return a new
  // array of updated objects
  return data.map(obj => {
  
    const newIds = obj.parentIds.filter(id => {
      return keys.includes(id);
    });

    return { ...obj, parentIds: newIds };
  
  });

}

console.log(removeIds(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well basic way would be to go trough array every time there is a change, and update parentIds list.

To do that:

```
  const dummyArray = [
    {id:1,parentIds:[]},
    {id:2,parentIds:[1,3]},
    {id:3,parentIds:[1,2,4]}
  ];
  /* You can do this with regular array, this only ensures that ids are unique */
  const idsSet = new Set();

  dummyArray.forEach(it =>  idsSet.add(it.id));
  dummyArray.forEach(it => {
      /* If you are using array, you would need to loop trough for each id and check if existing */
      const newParentIds = it.parentIds.filter(id => idsSet.has(id));
      it.parentIds = newParentIds;
      console.log(it.parentIds);
  });
```

There would be a better solution for this for sure, so please try to take this as an example for logic which can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, parentIds: [] },
  { id: 2, parentIds: [1, 3] },
  { id: 3, parentIds: [1, 2, 4] },
];
const removeParentIds = (array) => {
  return array.map((item) => {
    const { parentIds } = item;
    return {
      ...item,
      parentIds: parentIds.filter((parentId) => array.some((item) => item.id === parentId)),
    };
  });
}
console.log(removeParentIds(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add childIds in each object, so when you remove one object you can go through each of child's and remove from it's parents as-well.

```
const array = [ 
    {id:1,parentIds:[],childIds:[2,3]},
    {id:2,parentIds:[1,3],childIds:[3]},
    {id:3,parentIds:[1,2],childIds:[2]}
]


function idChecker(id){
    for(let i=0; i<array.length;i++) if(array[i].id === id) return i;
    return undefined
}


function removeObject(id){
    let key = idChecker(id)
    if(key === undefined) return false
    let children = array[key].childIds
    children.map(val => {
        let keyOfVal = idChecker(val)
        array[keyOfVal].parentIds.splice(array[keyOfVal].parentIds.indexOf(id), 1)
    })
    array.splice(idChecker(id), 1)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through inner parentIds array and remove members that are not any of the outer ids.

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, parentIds: [] },
  { id: 2, parentIds: [1, 3] },
  { id: 3, parentIds: [1, 2, 4] }
];

array.forEach(
  (o) =>
    (o.parentIds = o.parentIds.filter((pI) =>
      array.map((o) => o.id).includes(pI)
    ))
);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This one is even worse than what I just commented at *EzioMercer's* and *Soufiane's* approaches. Here the array of `id`'s gets created with every invocation of `filter` again and again (instead of doing it exactly once). Since this happens within the 2nd nested loop this puts unnecessary load into the computation task.

Comment: If the original array has just 3 members, efficiency shouldn't be a problem. But if the code should run with an array of about 500+ members then performance should really be considered. For the record, the person who asked the question didn't mention performance so I didn't worry about that either.

Comment: ... not quite agreed ... from my experience such approaches very often match with a certain attitude.